# Деление огромного числа

Tags: c#

Есть огромное число в виде текстовой строки, 24 десятичных знака в длину (например, `345678923456789876543234`). Это число надо разделить на другое, достаточно малое число (например, `97`).

Как выполнить деление, если из-за длины числа недоступен даже `long` и `ulong`?

Comment: Но ведь результат деления например на 97 будет на порядок меньше. Вы беспокоитесь, что не влезут 23 цифры результата, но совершенно не волнуетесь за 24 исходных цифры?

Answer (score 21):

Воспользуйтесь структурой [`BigInteger`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Console.WriteLine(BigInteger.Parse("345678923456789876543234") / 97);
// выдаёт 3563700241822576046837
```

Не забудьте подключить сборку System.Numerics.

---

Если нужно и частное, и остаток, то делайте так:

```
BigInteger dividend = BigInteger.Parse("345678923456789876543234");
BigInteger quotient = dividend / 97;
BigInteger remainder = dividend % 97;
```

(ну или воспользуйтесь [`BigInteger.DivRem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.numerics.biginteger.divrem(v=vs.110).aspx), если хотите).
Остаток можно скастить в `int`, т. к. он помещается туда:

```
int remainder = (int)(dividend % 97);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, но мне надо в форме(WindowsForms) и я пытался привязать к переменной не получается... Туповот-с...

Comment: @WaldemarKarsten полученный результат приводите к строке и потом уже привязывайте куда вам там нужно на форме.

Comment: Я понимаю что выражаюсь как-то сумбурно... Первый раз я задаю вопрос и поэтому надеюсь на снисхождение... есть переменная. В нее надо записать огромное число и потом с ней работать... Число получается путем манипуляций... тексты между собой складываются. 24 числовых знака получается. необходимо эту переменную потом преобразовать в число.  Потом надо из этого числа получить модуль 97  (остаток от деления на 97) и записать его в переменную. Вот такая задачка. Если можете помогите. Числа будут конечно потом разные... Поэтому все делается через переменные. Складываются тексты и так далее

Comment: Ну, задачу преобразования текста в число и проведения операции  решает приведённый код. Переменная в которой вы храните модуль должна быть какого-то строго определённого типа? Почему бы вам не сделать её типом BigInteger? Ну или string'ом на худой конец и каждый раз когда возникает необходимость выполнить операцию над числом приводить его в BigInteger? Если вам нужен работающий код решающий вашу проблему-увы, его скорее всего тут не будет.

Comment: @WaldemarKarsten: Ну, не выводите на консоль, а запишите в переменную типа `BigInteger`, проблем быть не должно.

Comment: @WaldemarKarsten: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо. Вы мне очень помогли. Всем Большое спасибо.

Comment: @WaldemarKarsten: Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 5):

## Если [BigInteger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx) недоступен

Разбейте число на части, например, поделите отдельно "*слева направо*", добавляя остаток от деления левой части к правой, пока не дойдете до самой "правой", которую поделите обычным способом, и соедините результат в одно число (или строку, если не влезет)

Comment: Да, именно так, как в школе учили столбиком делить, так и делите и не нужно будет переживать за переполнение.

Answer (score 1):

Навскидку:

```
using System.Numerics;
...
//Ваша строка, полученная путем манипуляций.
string yourStringNumber = "345678923456789876543234";
//Преобразуем строку в число. 
BigInteger big = BigInteger.Parse(yourStringNumber); 
//это ваш делитель, равный сейчас 97.
int divider = 97; 
//Получаем остаток от деления на 97.... Ну или что у вас там будет в переменную divider записано.
BigInteger result = big % divider;
//Вывод результата строкой на форму, в контрол label1 или... 
label1.Text = result.ToString(); 
//...Показываем число строкой в отдельном модальном окне. И так далее....
MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Из комментариев ясно что требуется вычислить остаток, не частное. Остаток от деления очень длинного числа на не очень длинное можно сделать без использования `BigInteger`:

```
using System;

int rem(String n, int d)
{
    int r = 0;
    foreach (char c in n)
    {
        r = (10 * r + (c - '0')) % d;
    }
    return r;
}

string[] tokens = Console.ReadLine().Split();
Console.WriteLine(rem(tokens[0], int.Parse(tokens[1])));
```

> ```
> $ csc -nologo rem.cs
>
> $ echo 345678923456789876543234 97 | mono rem.exe
> 45
> ```